# Get the first item of linkedhashmap

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I am using `LinkedHashMap`. I will always process the first value and that can be deleted (if possible) so that during the next iteration I will again take the same first value from the map to process. What can I use to get the first value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this to get the first element key:

```
 Object key = linkedHashMap.keySet().iterator().next();
```

then to get the value:

```
Object value = linkedHashMap.get(key);
```

and finally to remove that entry:

```
linkedHashMap.remove(key);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the an Iterator on the value set - e.g.

```
Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
map.put("A", 1);
map.values().iterator().next();
```

From your question, it's not clear to me that a map is the best object to use for your current task.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to require the value and key it is best to use the EntrySet.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
Entry<Integer, String> mapEntry = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
Integer key = mapEntry.getKey();
String value = mapEntry.getValue();
```